# Is is possible to create a Stripe refund action in Zapier?

Tags: stripe-payments, zapier

The create refund action is currently in pipeline on the Stripe integration for Zapier and isn't supported as of today. Support at Zapier suggested that I should post a question here to see if someone could point me in the right direction for creating this (if at all possible). Maybe the "Code by Zapier" or "Webhooks by Zapier" integration is a workaround that can be used? https://stripe.com/docs/refunds

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. That's definitely something you can do, though it'll take some programming work on your part.

You'll need a Stripe API key (which can be found in your dashboard). You'll want to use a Code by Zapier step in your preferred language and make the request described here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#create_refund. You'll need to get access to a charge id, which could be pulled from a New Charge trigger or Find Charge action.

Hopefully that points you in the right direction!